# Switchmap on same function

Tags: rxjs, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I am not a rxjs expert.

I have a method which actually does a save.

```
 this.saveProducts(this.boxes, 'BOXES')
```

But there are two other different type of items that needs to use the same method for saving , just the parameter is different.

```
 this.saveProducts(this.containers, 'CONTAINER')
```

In my component I have few other independent saving is happening and all these should happen one by one.

So my method look like this.

```
 return this.service.edit(materials)
        .do((data) => {
            this.materials= data;
        })
        .switchMap(() => this.customerService.addCustomer(this.id, this.customers))
        .switchMap(() => this.saveProducts(this.boxes, 'BOXES'))
        .switchMap(() => this.saveProducts(this.containers, 'CONTAINER'))
        .switchMap(() => this.saveProducts(this.books, 'BOOKS'))
        .do(() => {
         .......
            }
```

But whats happening is it never calls the second saveProducts method unless I have a return from first one

```
    private saveProducts(products: IProduct[], type: 
Type): Observable<any> {
        console.log(type);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for anyone who looked at it.. 
 The answer to this issue is to return an empty observable if nothing is there to save.

```
  if (products$.length === 0) {
        return Observable.of([]);
    }
```

Thanks guys.. Happy coding..